# JDBC Connection pool configuration in Tomcat 7

Tags: jdbc, tomcat7, connection-pooling

I added following properties in our context.xml file, under tomcat 7x

```
validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
testOnBorrow="true"
logValidationErrors="true"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
logAbandoned="true" 
maxActive="50" 
maxIdle="20" 
removeAbandoned="true" 
removeAbandonedTimeout="180"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
```

and I had shut down my Oracle database, and tried to connect the database through the application and I was getting exceptions as

```
### Error updating database.  Cause:       org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

Which I think is an expected error.

After that, I brought back the Oracle and tried to connect the database through application, with out restarting tomcat. My expectation is, the application should be able to get the connection from the pool and work as normal.  However, I saw

```
### Cause: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
; SQL []; Closed Connection; nested exception is  java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection
```

Is the SQLRecoverableException, expected here. Do I need to restart tomcat, to establish a successfull connection back to database? In a typical production environments, if DB is shutdown for any reason and was brought back, should the application servers also need to be restarted. I think, it is not required.

Did I miss any other property in Context.xml that enables this ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Kumar, I've the same problem. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify a url attribute that allows the connections to connect to the DB